# angularjs variables in the view not changing when scope change

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. But i have a serious problem. And i have been stuck at this point for the last 48 hours. Now my problem:

My view is not updating even when i update the variable in the controller. here's the code.

```
var stData;
function mainCtrl($scope,$http){

retrieveDataset($scope,$http,  'http://localhost:8080/ramap-service/DataProvider?title='+$scope.title+'&year='+$scope.year);  

$scope.$apply($scope.changeMap = function(){          
    var curl = 'http://localhost:8080/ramap-service/DataProvider?title='+$scope.title+'&year='+$scope.year;
    console.log(curl);        
    showDialog();
    retrieveDataset($scope,$http,curl);                              
});
function retrieveDataset($scope,$http, curl){
 $http.get(curl).success(function (data,status){        
     console.log(data.description); 
     $scope.desc = data.description;
     loadColors(data.results);
     stData=data.results;
     handleKeys($scope,data.results);        
 }).error(function(data,status){
     console.log(data);
 });
}

}

function loadColors(data){
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){        
    for(var j=0;j<paths.length;j++){
        var path = paths[j];
        if(data[i][4]===path.id){                 
            path.style.fill=getColor(data[i][5],data);                
            break;
        }
    }
}
}

function getColor(amount, data){
var color;    
var segments = segmentThem(data);
if(amount<=segments[1]){
    color = '#FFE5E9';
}else if(amount<segments[2]){
    color = '#FF657B';
}else if(amount < segments[3]){
    color = '#B20019';
}else if(amount < segments[4]){
    color = '#4C000B';
}else if (amount<segments[5]){
    color = '#FFB1BC';
}else if (amount <segments[6]){
    color = '#7E0012';
}else{
    color = '#FE0024';
}
return color;              
}

function segmentThem(data){
var min = findMin(data);
var max = findMax(data);
var diff = max - min;
var interval =diff/7;    
interval = Math.round(interval);
interval = roundSpecially(interval);    
var amounts = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    if(i===0){
        amounts[i]=min;
        continue;
    }
    var prev = parseInt(i)-1;
    amounts[i] = amounts[prev]+interval;

}
return amounts;
}

function findMin(data){  
var least =Number(data[0][5]);
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var num = Number(data[i][5]);
    if(num<least){
        least=num;
    }
}
return least;
}

function findMax(data){
var max = Number(data[0][5]);
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var num = Number(data[i][5]);
    if(num>max){
        max=num;
    }
}
return max;
}

function handleKeys($scope,data){
var segments = segmentThem(data);
var result = new Array();
var denom = 0;
if((segments[4]/1000000000)>0.99){
    denom = 1000000000;
}else if ((segments[4]/1000000)>0.99){
    denom = 1000000;
}else if((segments[4]/1000)>0.99){
    denom = 1000;
}else{
    denom = 100;
}
for(var i=0; i<segments.length;i++){
    result[i] = segments[i]/denom;
}       
$scope.denom = denom;
$scope.results = result;
}

function roundSpecially(num){
num = num+'';
var length = num.length-1;
var re = num[0];
for(var i=0; i<length;i++){
    re=re+'0';
}
return Number(re);
}

function showInfo(){
var event = window.event;
var element = event.srcElement;
var data = getData(element.id);    
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML= '<b>'+data[3]+'</b>'+"<br>"+currency('N', data[5]);   
}

function getData(id){  
var result;
for(var i=0;i<stData.length;i++){
    if(id===stData[i][4]){
        result = stData[i];                        
    }
}
if(typeof result === 'undefined'){
    return alert("This program has some undefined values on line 224");
}else{
    return result;
}  

}

function currency(sSymbol, vValue) {
 vValue = Number(vValue);
 var aDigits = vValue.toFixed(2).split(".");
 aDigits[0] = aDigits[0].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g,  "$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
  return sSymbol + aDigits.join(".");
 }

function showDialog(){
 var el = document.getElementById("myOverlay");
  el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility==='hidden')?'visible':'hidden';
}
```

and then my view is like this:

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<header>
    <img src="img/header3.png"/>
</header>
<aside >
    <h5 >About the Current dataset</h5>
    <p class="points" >Title</p>    
          {{title}} {{year}}
    <p class="points">Description</p>
        {{desc}}
</aside>
<div  id="colorcode" >
    <h5>Map key</h5>
   ({{denom|currency:"N"}})
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Range</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#FFE5E9;"></td>
    <td >{{results[0]}} - {{results[1]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  style="background:#FF657B;"></td>
    <td >{{results[1]}} - {{results[2]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#B20019"></td>
    <td >{{results[2]}} - {{results[3]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#4C000B"></td>
    <td>{{results[3]}} - {{results[4]}}</td>
    <tr>
    <td style="background:#FFB1BC;"></td>
    <td>{{results[4]}} - {{results[5]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#7E0012"></td>
    <td>{{results[5]}} - {{results[6]}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#FE0024"></td>
    <td>Above {{results[6]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<span onclick="showDialog()" id="editspan"><i class="icon-edit icon-2x"></i><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Change Dataset"/></span>
<div id="info">    
</div>
<div id="map">      
    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="797" height="710" viewBox="0 0 297 210" >
  <style type="text/css">
    .state {fill:#FF0000; stroke:white ; stroke-width:0.5; stroke-opacity:1;}
  </style>

</svg>
</div>
<div id="myOverlay">
    <table id="dtable">

                          <tr id="row">
                            <td id="dtd"><form id="dialogue_box">
                        <div class="box1"><label id="label">Dataset title:</label></td>
                            <td id="dtd"> <select ng-model="title" value="budget works dataset">
                          <option value="budget works dataset" id="box" >Budget Works Dataset</option>                         
                        </select></td>
                          </tr></div>
                          <tr>
                            <td id="dtd"><div class="box1"><label id="label2">Specify Year: </td>
                            <td id="dtd"></label><select class="first" ng-model="year" >
                                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                          <option value="2010">2010</option>
                          <option value="2011">2011</option>
                          <option value="2012">2012</option>
                          <option value="2013">2013</option>                                                    
                        </select></td>
                          </tr></div>

                            <tr>
                                <td id="submit"><button id="button" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-click="changeMap()"> Enter</button><button id="button" onclick="showDialog()"> Cancel</button></td>
                            </tr>

                        </form></div>

                        </table>
</div>
```

but none of these varibles are changing.

Comment: By not "changing" do you mean you still see the templated values? like `{{desc}}`?  And, where is `ng-app` defined?

Comment: No. The tags work perfectly as the page loads. but when an event fired that runs the `$scope.changeMap` function which in turn updates `{{desc}}` and the other scope variables i do not see the reflection on the page. Also ng-app is defined in the <html> tag.

Comment: Try $scope.$apply($scope.changeMap()); that shoul tell the DOM it needs to update.

Comment: @AmbroseAriagiegbe You cannot have a model definition inside $scope.$apply(). So you need to move $scope.changeMap outside $apply().

Answer (score 0):

If you properly indent the code you can see that the controller is only updating the code in the aside element and the rest of the page isn't within the MainCtrl's scope.  Also a few other tags were in the wrong order.  This template should fix your problems.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <aside>
        <h5>
            About the Current dataset
        </h5>
        <p class="points">
            Title
        </p>
        {{ititle}} {{iyear}}
        <p class="points">
            Description
        </p>
        {{desc}}
    </aside>
    <div id="myOverlay">
        <table id="dtable">
            <tr id="row">
                <td id="dtd">
                    <form id="dialogue_box">
                        <div class="box1">
                            <label id="label">
                                Dataset title:
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td id="dtd">
                    <select ng-model="title" value="budget works dataset">
                        <option value="budget works dataset" id="box">
                            Budget Works Dataset
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="dtd">
                    <div class="box1">
                        <label id="label2">
                            Specify Year:
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="dtd">
                    </label>
                    <select class="first" ng-model="year">
                        <option value="2009">
                            2009
                        </option>
                        <option value="2010">
                            2010
                        </option>
                        <option value="2011">
                            2011
                        </option>
                        <option value="2012">
                            2012
                        </option>
                        <option value="2013">
                            2013
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="submit">
                    <button id="button" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-click="changeMap()">
                        Enter
                    </button>
                    <button id="button" onclick="showDialog()">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now there is a containing div with the ng-controller="mainCtrl" tag and that should update the rest of the template now that everything is in scope.

Comment: I tried it out but still didn't work for me. I have edited the code and added the full sources concerned. I appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a lot of code (you should've break it down to narrow your problem) I share my thoughts what might be the problem. Sorry not to be more precise, but your example is quite big and there are many pitfalls.

You are loading some data from a webserver. When you get that result, you are writing the retrieved data to a local variable `stData` and call some other function inside the result handler, which seems to be ok.
But in your `showInfo() { getData(){...} }` function you are working with `stData` and expect it to hold the latest data - this is not guaranteed.

I would suggest that you overthink your overall workflow of your retrieved data and do everything in the result handler. Store `stData` in `$scope.stData`, this way angular has a chance to know about your incoming data.

Also you are referencing the DOM in your mainCtrl which is never a good idea. Working with the DOM cries for implementing a directive.

I also suggest that you work through the angular-phonecat tutorial http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 and once complete, you change it according to your needs. You will learn a lot of things, including:

- Separate DOM manipulations into directives
- Create modules containing service-factories
- usage of `$resource` (for service calls)
- usage of injection
- get a better feel about the angular scope mechanism and the `$digest` lifecycle ( $apply() )

So the basic steps would be to

- seperate service calls into a service factory using $resource
- inject that service into your Controller and do the call.
- reduce working on the dom - no need for any document.getElementById and such ;)
- move all your helper functions to a service, you might call it toolService and also inject that service in your Controller.

This will cleanup your code a lot, every part has its responsibilites and this helps you when looking for bugs.

Happy coding :)